# why can't catalyic converters mailed to california

Tags: catalytic-converter

Why doesn't California let other states ship converters to us residents?  I'll have to pay outragest ca prices?

Comment: it's the law my guy. California has different emissions laws than all other 49 states. They happen to be the strictest.

Comment: For the same reason you cannot import fruit from other States? They're afraid one cat is going to bring bugs in with them, infect their good cats, and then all the cats would be bad. I'm *pretty* sure that's the reason. Hmmm ... I wonder if @finleyarcher is onto something, though ;-) Yah, CARB laws really suck. They've gone off the deep end, especially with cats. [Here's a pretty good FAQ](https://www.arb.ca.gov/msprog/aftermktcat/installcatq&a.pdf) which spells out a lot of it, but doesn't *specifically* answer your question.

Comment: Although, I though about it after you answered @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 :)   you can order catalytic converters from other states  ..they just have to be california legal. https://www.amazon.com/Magnaflow-45419-California-Catalytic-Converter/dp/B0025QI2WK this company is based out of utah but selling cali stuff. so I am not sure what answer I could write for this. California does.

Comment: @finleyarcher - I think there's your answer. It's pretty specific what you *can* use as far as cats go, so slim pickens all the way around.

Comment: Thanks to the two answers above I just would like to know why not NY is Utah the only one. ( just wondering) All the parts I've got are from 1A auto, they have everything I need. Thanks @paulster2 and the other one damnitdog

Comment: Not only do they need to be CA legal, the seller has to warranty them for 5 years.  That alone would cause me to simply refuse to ship to CA if I was in that business.